# Swift 4 iOS: Does not discover services of connected BLE device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to make an app that is able to configure a Bluetooth Low Energy device. As it is now that app connects to the device, but as I understand the app wont discover the services of the BLE devices.

I know the BLE devices has a number of services because there already is an Android app, that is able to configure the same device.

My connection code is as follows:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    if peripheral.name == "Sensor"{
        if let name = peripheral.name {
            foundPeripherals.append(name)

            sensor = peripheral
            sensor.delegate = self
            centralManager.connect(sensor, options: nil)

        } else {
            foundPeripherals.append(peripheral.identifier.uuidString)
        }
        RSSIs.append(RSSI)
        if peripheral.name != nil {
            // For viewing the data in the console
            print("--->Peripheral device<---")
            print("Name: \(peripheral.name as Any)")
            print("UUID: \(peripheral.identifier.uuidString)")
            print("RSSI: \(RSSI)")
            print(" -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - ")
            print(advertisementData)
        }
        connectTableView.reloadData()

    }
}


func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("-->Connected to Sensor<--")
    print("Sensor info: \(peripheral)")
    centralManager?.stopScan()

    peripheral.delegate = self

    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)

}
```

But I get this output in my console:

```
--->Scanning started<---
--->Peripheral device<---
Name: Optional("Sensor")
UUID: 1AC3DC85-61E0-C3E9-0E33-D98F1D1CA791
RSSI: -43
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs": <__NSArrayM 0x2814852c0>(
6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E
)
, "kCBAdvDataIsConnectable": 1, "kCBAdvDataLocalName": Sensor]
-->Connected to Sensor<--
Sensor info: <CBPeripheral: 0x282bd0820, identifier = 1AC3DC85- 
61E0-C3E9-0E33-D98F1D1CA791, name = Sensor, state = connected>
2018-10-03 14:56:31.029079+0200 Sensor[9686:3266937] 
[CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: Discovering services for peripheral 
<CBPeripheral: 0x282bd0820, identifier = 1AC3DC85-61E0-C3E9-0E33- 
D98F1D1CA791, name = Sensor, state = connected> while delegate is 
either nil or does not implement peripheral:didDiscoverServices:
```

It does not discover/show any services

Hope it makes sense and you guys are able to help

-Thomas

Comment: And where is your implementation of `func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?)`? That's what is saying the error: `[CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: Discovering services for peripheral ... while delegate is 
either nil or does not implement peripheral:didDiscoverServices:` Because you did a `discoverServices` but didn't implement the related delegate method. It's stated "MISUSE" and to implement the method.

Comment: I have now tried adding :

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        for service: CBService in peripheral.services! {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            print(service)
        }
    }

and is now getting:
"while delegate is either nil or does not implement peripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:error:"

So I should now add didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService?

Comment: Because you did `peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)`, you get that exact "same" message. You need to implement the `didDiscoverCharacteristic` delegate method. If you don't care about the characteristics, you don't need to implement it, but clearly, then don't discover them.

Comment: @Larme I am not totally sure what you mean with "didDiscoverCharacteristic delegate method". I have added the following:

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        for characteristics: CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics! {
            print(characteristics)
        }
    }

Comment: That's the one. It just that I don't know the exact name of the method. Also, it's a delegate method (it's part of `CBPeripheralDelegate`), `delegate` being a design pattern quite used on iOS. After all, you wrote `peripheral.delegate = self`.

Comment: Ah okay, for some reason my mind jumped to something along the lines of CBPeripheralDelegate. But THANK YOU SO MUCH! Now I get this printed in the console:

-->Service<--
<CBService: 0x28195b5c0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E>
-->Characteristic<--
<CBCharacteristic: 0x2828c3360, UUID = 6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties = 0x10, value = (null), notifying = NO>
-->Characteristic<--
<CBCharacteristic: 0x2828c27c0, UUID = 6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties = 0xC, value = (null), notifying = NO>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import message in console:

> [CoreBluetooth] **API MISUSE**: Discovering services for peripheral  <
>   CBPeripheral: 0x282bd0820, identifier =
>   1AC3DC85-61E0-C3E9-0E33-D98F1D1CA791, name = Sensor, state =
>   connected> **while delegate is either nil or does not implement
>   peripheral:didDiscoverServices:**

You are misusing the CoreBluetooth Framework.

You wrote `peripheral.discoverServices(nil)` which leads to that error in console.
Since it's not the part *while delegate is either nil* since you wrote before `peripheral.delegate = self`, it means it's the part *while delegate does not implement `peripheral:didDiscoverServices:`*.

In Swift, it's `peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:)`, or more explicitly `optional func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?)`

After saying so, you implemented it, did `peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)` and got *while delegate is either nil or does not implement `peripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:error:`*.

You see the analogy the with the previous issue? So implement `peripheral(_:didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor:error:)` or more explicitly: `optional func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?)`